# android java passing data from view to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, ondraw

i'm starting with drawing in android.

I have simple activity with only onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set full screen view
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    drawView = new DrawView(this, height, width);
    setContentView(drawView);
    drawView.requestFocus();        
}
```

In the drawView i have used onDraw method to draw circles every time i tap the screen. Circles are drawed where i tap. 
When the app detects there's no more possibility to add circle i want to get back to my main activity and start another actions.
Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: DrawView is your custom view  and logic of detection of no more Circle is in the DrawView right ? 

so why you not pass the activity in constructor of DrawView  and use n you logic?

Comment: Dheeresh Singh,
thanks a lot. I didn't believe it's so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of object oriented programing here.  With an object oriented program there is no clear path your program follows.  You create a series of objects and teach them how to handle events.

If your drawView is done its work then remove it from view and put somthing else in its place for the user to interact with.

It is that simple.

In your case your drawview is an axctivity.  When you  are done with it you should call another activity.  I suggest re-reading this [dev guide section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).

The best way to learn and understand is to find an open source app (Google's own apps are best) that does something similar and study its source code.